# Angular queryParams Subscription does not fire (checkbox for check all)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have an application where you can select between several regions that you want to display data from. Above the checkboxes of those regions I added a main checkbox "AllRegions" which obv. selects/unselects all other checkboxes.
This works fine, the parameters are posted to the url and all that.

The only problem I have is when I check/uncheck the "AllRegions" checkbox my component does not react to the subscription of parameter change. It works when unchecking single regions, but not with this "AllRegions" even though I call the same function.

Component:

```
        ngOnInit() {
            this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.loadRegionData();
            })
        }
```

This code is called when I click the checkbox.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.createUrlTree([url], { queryParams: { regions: regionParameters } }));
```

Why is the subscription in ngOnInit not fired when I navigateByUrl?

Answer (score 1):

If the getSelectedRegions returns an Observable, it will not be triggered because you arent subscribing to it (internal observable). I would recommend you to refactor into the following (asuming route is of type *ActivatedRoute*):

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.route.queryParams
        .switchMap(params => this.regionsService.getSelectedRegions())
        .subscribe(
         //handle *data* and *error*
        );
    }
```

Comment: I tried similar code too, but it's not what I'm looking for.
I updated my code. It's not about the "getSelectedRegions" Function.
I subscribed to the route.queryParams and as soon as the Parameters in the URL change I want to do some code. Added the new Function "this.loadRegionData()" so maybe this makes more sense.

Whenever the parameters change I want to load my RegionData again.
This worked perfectly for my single checkboxes but for some reason the subscription does not fire if all checkboxes are unchecked at the same time.